# Can not connect to internet via wifi

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-vista, internet

My laptop, acer, vista, will not connect to internet even though the wifi connection is excellent, I have a wireless router N and am receiving internet service via hughesnet gen4. Have NO problem connecting via ethernet, ??? Had everything tested and all is fine, what else can I do to get wifi?? Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: Have you rebooted the wifi access point/router to see if that might help? This would be my first attempt at fixing a wonky wifi connection. Do other devices connect and work on the wifi?

Answer (score 1):

Need more info, so here's a general troubleshooting list that's too long for a comment:

1. Reboot the laptop, the router, and the modem, grab a coffee. If the problem persists you'll need the coffee. You can restart them all at the same time, but if you want to be super careful, you turn off all 3 devices, then turn them on one after another, with 30 seconds in between, starting with the modem, then the router, and finally the laptop. This rarely matters.
2. Turn off your WiFi router. If your WiFi is still connected to a WiFi network, it's connected to the wrong one.
3. Try to get another device working with the WiFi router, maybe even with an ethernet cable. From your question it isn't clear if the devices with working ethernet connection are connected to the WiFi router, or to another device.
4. Check IP settings. Do you use a fixed IP or DHCP on the laptop? If you use a fixed IP, someone else may be using the same IP.
5. Try to access another machine on the same local network from the laptop.

Comment: You should power off all equipment. Then restart modem first. Then Router. Then laptop. In that order (not "reboot the laptop, the router, and the modem" - that is the reverse or what you should do).

Comment: I have done all the steps several times, other than IP address changes. how do I know if the laptop is using DHCP ?

Comment: @lilly Here's a guide: http://windows7themes.net/en-us/how-to-enable-dhcp-in-windows-7/ notice that where it say's ethernet, you need to select your WiFi instead.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with your IP configuration, please try one oof the below methods to assign IP address automatically and check the results,

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Click Network and Internet.
3. Click View network status and tasks.
4. Click Change adapter settings.
5. Right click the wireless adapter and select Properties.
6. Select Internet Protocol Version 4.
7. Click Properties.
8. Tick both obtain automatically boxes.
9. Click OK

Alternatively you can try the below commands from command line
"ipconfig/release"
"ipconfig/renew"

Comment: I do believe that it is an IP problem, but this solution didn't work neither. i am having a tech coming out tomorrow and we shall see why it does this and if we can remedy this. I am on Satellite Internet access and should be able to just hook any router into my modem, but there is something not correct here.